# UITapGestureRecognizer locationPoint on different devices

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, xcode11

I would like to get the location point when I tap somewhere on an image. The issue is depending on which device/resolution (iphones, ipads, etc..) I don't get the same coordinate.

I'm looking at a way to get the same location regardless of the devices/resolution.

```
@IBAction func tapGestureAction(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let gestureView = tapGesture.view else {
        return
    }

    let tappedLocationPoint = tapGesture.location(in: gestureView)
    print(tappedLocationPoint.x)
    print(tappedLocationPoint.y)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your layout? Or what do you mean by getting the same coordinates? Same relative to the screen?

Comment: The layout is just an UIImageView on the entire screen with the AspectFit set. But because of different resolution, the image is smaller than the screen. I think I need to know the new size of the image or by how much the image has been scaled down?

Comment: You'll get the location in the image view. You'll need to either resize the image view to be as large as the actual image, or to compute the size of the image and offset all the touches.

Comment: @VladRusu yes I think compute the size of the image and offset all the touches is the best solution, but how to implement such a thing. It's not quite easy as the image has AspectFit and also the device orientation might come into play as well.

Comment: You have to know the width/height of the image & width/height of the image view. Then you can find out which dimension does not fit the whole frame of the image view: horizontal or vertical. And also find out what is the gap not filled.